# Why are SA OC 61:22 and 61:23 in that order?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, pronunciation, shema, shulchan-aruch, pesukei-dezimra

*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* [61:20–1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.61.20-21?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), dicattes that, when reading "*Sh'ma*", one must put a space between words that are in danger of being run together.

In the following paragraph, [:22](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.61.22?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), it says "One must be careful about this matter in *p'suke d'zimra* and prayer also." (The *Rama* there extends it to reading *Tanach* aloud, incidentally.)

And then, in [:23](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.61.23?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), the *SA* adds two more rules: to distinguish *sh'va nach* from *na* and a letter with a *dagesh* from one without.

Why does the broadening principle of :22 (seemingly) apply to :20–1 and not to :23?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*Shulchan Aruch*'s organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch#Structure) is based on that of the [*Tur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arba%27ah_Turim). In particular, here, the laws listed in the question are presented in the same order, with the same section-numbering, [in the *Tur*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x164). So, the question is why :22 and :23 are in that order in the *Tur*.

When the *Tur* presents the laws in 61:16-22, it does so without explicitly citing sources, presumably indicating that either these laws were not matters of controversy to earlier authorities or that the author felt comfortable implicitly choosing sides if there were any such controversies. However, in 61:23, the *Tur* cites the laws about *sheva* and *dagesh* in the name of the [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides), and then quotes the [Raavad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David) as objecting specifically to the Rambam's rule against pronouncing a *sheva nach* as a *sheva na*. (The *Shulchan Aruch*, in mentioning the Rambam's opinion but not the Raavad's implicitly decides in favor of the former, consistent with its author's explicit disagreement with the Raavad, expressed in his *Beit Yosef* commentary on *Tur* 61:23.)

So, perhaps the *Tur* presented this particular law after all of the others about pronunciation because its details weren't universally accepted by previous authorities. I'm not sure if such late-ordering of more-controversial rules is standard in the *Tur*, but I'll note that the remaining two sections in that chapter, :24 and :25, both also contain citation notes, in that the former is cited in the name of Rabeinu Yona, and the latter includes a "And there are those whose practice is ..." note.